# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the error from the code:

```js
state: {
 route: 'signin',
  isSignedIn: false,
  news: {},
  weather: {},
  sports: [],
  clothes: {},
  selectedTeam: "",
  user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    profimg: '',
    images: [],
    tasks: []
  }
}

newTask = task => {
  const { user, tasks } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    user: {
      ...user,
      tasks: [
        ...tasks,
        task
      ]
    }
  })
}
```

I provided the state structure, and the function.
What is the problem? What the error means as non-iterable?

Comment: Is `user` a `key-value` object?

Comment: user is a key-value object. I provide it for the example

Comment: And what about the `tasks`?

Comment: But tasks can be the empty array as above. But it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: UM, tasks is in user.....

Comment: `tasks` is inside of user `(:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `tasks` is inside of object `user`.

You can execute a destructure statement as follow:

```
const { user, tasks = [user] } = this.state
```

```js
let state = {
 route: 'signin',
  isSignedIn: false,
  news: {},
  weather: {},
  sports: [],
  clothes: {},
  selectedTeam: "",
  user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    profimg: '',
    images: [],
    tasks: ['EleFromStack']
  }
};

let newTask = task => {
  const { user, tasks = [user] } = state;  
  console.log(JSON.stringify({
    user: {
      ...user,
      tasks: [
        ...tasks,
        task
      ]
    }
  }, null, 2))
};

newTask('SOQuestion')
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```